# How export crystal report to excel in vb6

Tags: vb6

I am trying to export the report to msexcel, in windows server 2003 it works without problem, but when I want to execute it locally (windows 7) it only tells me that the report cannot be exported

This is the code I work with

```
Call SetParametros(ReporteCrystal)

    Select Case UCase(cmbTipo.Text)

    Case "PDF"
        ReporteCrystal.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTPortableDocFormat
        auxExtension = ".pdf"
    Case "MSWORD"
        ReporteCrystal.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTWordForWindows
        auxExtension = ".doc"
    Case "MSEXCEL"
        ReporteCrystal.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTExcel97
        auxExtension = ".xls"
    Case "TEXT"
        ReporteCrystal.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTTabSeparatedText
        auxExtension = ".txt"
    Case "MSEXCEL(SIN FORMATO)"
        ReporteCrystal.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTExcelDataOnly
        auxExtension = ".xls"
    End Select

   If Trim(StrNombreRealDelArchivo) <> "" Then
      strNombreDelReporte = StrNombreRealDelArchivo
   End If



    auxResult = Dir$(crEDTDiskFile & "\", vbDirectory)

   '******************************************************************************
   'SE COMENTO PORQUE NO PERMITIA ELEGIR EL FORMATO DE EXCEL CORRECTO
   'Y NOS ARROJABA UN ERROR CUANDO LO EXPORTABAS
   If UCase(cmbDestino.Text) = "DISCO" Then
     cd1.DialogTitle = "Seleccione la ubicacion del archivo"
     cd1.CancelError = True
     cd1.Filter = Replace(auxExtension, ".", "") & "|*" & auxExtension
     'CD1.Filter = strNombreDelReporte
     cd1.filename = strNombreDelReporte
     cd1.InitDir = crEDTDiskFile 'strMAILFolderContenedorDeDocumentos
     cd1.ShowSave
     auxDestino = cd1.filename
    'auxDestino = auxDestino & " \ " & strNombreDelReporte & auxExtension
   Else
    auxDestino = crEDTDiskFile & "\" & strNombreDelReporte & auxExtension
    'strMAILFolderContenedorDeDocumentos & "\" & strNombreDelReporte & auxExtension
   End If
   '******************************************************************************
'   auxDestino = strMAILFolderContenedorDeDocumentos & "\" & strNombreDelReporte & auxExtension

   If auxDestino = "" Then Exit Sub
   ReporteCrystal.ExportOptions.DiskFileName = auxDestino
   ReporteCrystal.ExportOptions.DestinationType = crEDTDiskFile

   '******************************************************************************
   'SE COMENTO PORQUE NO PERMITIA ELEGIR EL FORMATO DE EXCEL CORRECTO
   'Y NOS ARROJABA UN ERROR CUANDO LO EXPORTABAS
   ReporteCrystal.Export False
   '******************************************************************************

   '--con este codigo se permite exportar el reporte de crystal a excel con el formato del reporte
   'ReporteCrystal.Export True

   If UCase(cmbDestino.Text) = "CORREO" Then
       If strMAILDirigidoA = "" Then MsgBox "No existe correo destino", vbInformation, strSist: Exit Sub
       'Call EnviarAOutlookExpress(strMAILFolderContenedorDeDocumentos & "\" & strNombreDelReporte & auxExtension, strMAILDirigidoA, strMAILCuerpo, strMAILTema)
       ReDim arrMAILadjuntos(0)  '= strMAILFolderContenedorDeDocumentos & "\" & strNombreDelReporte & auxExtension
       arrMAILadjuntos(0) = strMAILFolderContenedorDeDocumentos & "\" & strNombreDelReporte & auxExtension
       frmEnviarCorreo.Show 1
   End If

   MsgBox "El reporte fue enviado", vbInformation, strSist
```

first I did not open the directory where I would save it, it already does but when wanting to save in xls it sends me the error "Cannot generate the file", when I export it to pdf,word,txt it does it without any problem,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the DLL for Excel. On my runtime deployments I have crxf_xls.dll and crxf_clx_res_en.dll (English, you'd have a different one), in 
c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Business Objects\3.0\bin\

The path may also vary depending how the components are installed and from which version. Search for crxf_pdf.dll since you said PDF export is working, and look in that location.